# Query in xslt path

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

This is my XML input:

```
<maindocument>
<first>
<testing>random text</testing>
<checking>random test</checking>
</first>
<testing unit = "yes">
<tested>sample</tested>
<checking>welcome</checking>
<import task="yes">
<downloading>sampledata</downloading>
</import>
<import section="yes">
<downloading>valuable text</downloading>
</import>
<import chapter="yes">
<downloading>checkeddata</downloading>
</import>
</testing>
</maindocument>
```

The output should be: first, it will check whether or not the testing unit = "yes". If it is, it has to check that the section attribute = "yes". This is the output:

```
<maindocument>
<import>
      <doctype>Valuable text</doctype>
</import>
</maindocument
```

I'm checking with `xsl:if` condition. First, it will check if the testing unit="yes". Then it will check whether the import section = "yes". The code is not able to achieve the above output.

Comment: What do you want to happen if testing unit="no", or if import section="no"?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="maindocument">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|testing[@unit='yes']/import[@section='yes']"/>          
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="import/@*"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<maindocument>
   <import>
      <downloading>valuable text</downloading>
   </import>
</maindocument>
```

If you don't want to keep any attributes in `<maindocument>`, remove the `@*|` from the `select` in `xsl:apply-templates` (in the `maindocument` template).

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

     <xsl:template match="/*">
      <maindocument>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="testing[@unit='yes']/import[@section='yes']"/>
      </maindocument>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="import">
      <import>
        <doctype><xsl:value-of select="*"/></doctype>
      </import>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<maindocument>
    <first>
        <testing>random text</testing>
        <checking>random test</checking>
    </first>
    <testing unit = "yes">
        <tested>sample</tested>
        <checking>welcome</checking>
        <import task="yes">
            <downloading>sampledata</downloading>
        </import>
        <import section="yes">
            <downloading>valuable text</downloading>
        </import>
        <import chapter="yes">
            <downloading>checkeddata</downloading>
        </import>
    </testing>
</maindocument>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<maindocument>
   <import>
      <doctype>valuable text</doctype>
   </import>
</maindocument>
```

Comment: Good answer (+1). Note, however, that the OP's desired output seems to have a `<doctype>` element, rather than a `<downloading>` one. Not sure if that's an error or intentional...

Comment: @ABach, Thanks for noticing this -- not a big deal to correct -- done.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you use `<doctype><xsl:value-of select="*"/></doctype>` instead of `<doctype><xsl:apply-templates /></doctype>`? Is your version more efficient in this scenario?

Comment: @ABach: `<xsl:apply-templates/>` causes templates to be applied to all child nodes -- including the whitespace-only ones. This would produce unwanted whitespace.